# Creating a table viable for t.test function

Tags: r

I am given a data frame with multiple variables but I am only interested in 2 variables and am required to group the variables into 2 groups. (i.e. group 1:mean age at child-birth with having 10+ years of education; group 2: mean age at child-birth with having less than 10 years of education) I am trying to figure out how to put this into a table but I am having troubles on how I can group the rows I want based on years of education. I currently have a table that looks like this with the following code:
'''

```
    means<-table(bfeed_df$ybirth,bfeed_df$yschool)
```

'''
giving me:
'''

```
        3 6 7 8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
    78  0 0 2 2  5   8  8 26  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
    79  1 2 2 3  6  12 12 38 10  5  0  0  0  0  0 
    80  0 0 0 5 10  11 13 38 10  5  2  0  0  0  0
    .
    .
```

'''

I want:

```
        <10years   +10years
    78       9          46
    79      14          77
    80      15          88
    .        .           .
    .        .           .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut` to divide `yschool` in two categories and use it in `table`.

```
means <- table(bfeed_df$ybirth,cut(bfeed_df$yschool, c(-Inf, 10, Inf)))
colnames(means) <- c('<10years',  '10+years')
means
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Let's generate some fake data that matches your input
temp = matrix(sample(60,60), ncol = 15)
colnames(temp) = c(3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
rownmes(temp) = c(78, 79, 80, 81)
#     3  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
# 78  5  4 21 13 18 17 34 43 19 41 55 36 12 52 15
# 79 56 14 38 28 30 25  8 44 35 59 39 49 20  2 58
# 80 22 27  3  9 33 54 26 50 53 45 10 40 48  7  6
# 81 42 46 23  1 60 57 47 16 24 51 37 32 11 29 31
```

Now we can create the summations using apply

```
sums = t(apply(temp, 1, function(x) c(sum(x[1:4]), sum(x[5:15])) ))
colnames(sums) = c("<10y","+10y")
sums

> sums
   <10y +10y
78   43  342
79  136  369
80   61  372
81  112  395
```

Is this what you are looking for?